# Como obter o nome do mês em um input type=month?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tenho um código que tem uma input do tipo month que gera um calendário com os valores passados na input, porém a mesma grava os valores nesse padrão 2000-12, e eu quero exibir o nome do mês em cima do calendário mas não é possível pois o mês é passado em dígitos, existe alguma forma de pegar os valores diretamente da input?

```html
<body>
        
        <?php
        
        $datee = explode('-', $_POST['datac']);
        $mes = $datee[1];
        $ano = $datee[0];
        $ultimo_dia = date("t", mktime(0,0,0,$mes,'01',$ano));
        if ($mes == date('m')){
            $dias = $ultimo_dia;
        }elseif ( $mes == '') {
            $mes = date('m');
            $ano = date('o');
            $dias = $ultimo_dia;
        }else{
            $dias = $ultimo_dia;
        }
    

            ?>
            <?php
            echo '<h4>'.$mes. ' de ' .$ano.'</h4>';
            ?>
    
            <form method="post" action="date.php">
                <input type="month" name="datac" value="<?php echo $ano?>-<?php echo $mes?>" required><input type="submit">
                <table class="table table-striped" width="210" border="2" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="80px"><center>Domingo</center></td>
                        <td width="80px"><center>Segunda</center></td>
                        <td width="80px"><center>Terça</center></td>
                        <td width="80px"><center>Quarta</center></td>
                        <td width="80px"><center>Quinta</center></td>
                        <td width="80px"><center>Sexta</center></td>
                        <td width="80px"><center>Sábado</center></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    echo "<tr>";
                    for ($i = 1; $i <= $dias; $i++) {
                        $diadasemana = date("w", mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, $i, $ano));
                        $cont = 0;
                        if ($i == 1) {
                            while ($cont < $diadasemana) {
                                echo "<td></td>";
                                $cont++;
                            }
                        }
                        echo "<td width='100px' height='100px'><center>";
                        echo $i;
                        echo "</center></td>";
                        if ($diadasemana == 6) {
                            echo "</tr>";
                            echo "<tr>";
                        }
                    }
                    echo "</tr>";
                    ?>
            </table>
                
    
                    </form>
                    </body>
                    </html>
```

Comment: Cole seu código aqui, se possível

Comment: jà o coloquei, ele está dando um erro por causa das variáveis indefinidas, mais funciona normalmente.

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi, você quer mostrar o nome do mês ao invés do número do mês ?

Comment: isso Mesmo :D!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abaixo vou citar algumas possíveis maneiras =>

```
    <?php
    ############################################################
    ############## Essas configurações podem ser settadas no seu servidor Web
    ###########################################################
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt_BR", "pt_BR.iso-8859-1", "pt_BR.utf-8", "portuguese");
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');


    $getMonthNum = 06;
    ############################################################

    echo strftime("%B", strtotime(date("Y-{$getMonthNum}-d")));

    ############################################################
    echo '<br>';
    $dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $getMonthNum);
    $mes = $dateObj->format('F');

    echo strftime('%B', $dateObj->getTimestamp());

    ##############################################################
    echo '<br>';
    $meses = array(1 => "Janeiro", 2 => "Fevereiro", 3 => "Março", 4 => "Abril", 5 => "Maio", 6 => "Junho",
        7 => "Julho", 8 => "Agosto", 9 => "Setembro", 10 => "Outubro", 11 => "Novembro", 12 => "Dezembro");

    echo $meses[$getMonthNum];
```

Outra coisa, ao invés de usar **`<center>`**, use **`style="text-align:center"`**. Porque **`<center>`** já esta DEPRECATED no HTML5

Comment: Valeu LucaoA!!!!!!

Comment: @Nikk17016 disponha. Mas se foi útil, me ajude com um voto heheh